# Is it possible programatically block scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I write datagrid with lazy loading, and for some reason I need stop scrolling, when user achieve area without data, to load it. I'm would like to know how I can stop scrolling on page from my code. I have tried `e.preventDefault`, `return false` from event handler and that solution also [**almost working solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4770179/3047033).

But problem is all of that solutions actually don't block scrolling, just emulate it. e.g. I want to block scrolling when `user` scroll up to `5000px`

```js
$(function() {
  var container = $(".container");
  var info = $(".info > .position");

  container.scroll(function(e) {
    var topPosition = container.scrollTop();
    if (topPosition >= 5000) {
      disableScroll();
    }
    info.text("scrollTop: " + topPosition);
  });

  $(".info > .disable").click(disableScroll);
  $(".info > .enable").click(enableScroll);
});

/*
 * Code from solution which was mentioned above
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily
 */
const keys = {
  37: 1,
  38: 1,
  39: 1,
  40: 1
};

function preventDefault(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.preventDefault)
    e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = false;
}

function preventDefaultForScrollKeys(e) {
  if (keys[e.keyCode]) {
    preventDefault(e);
    return false;
  }
}

function disableScroll() {
  $(".info > .state").text("Disable");
  if (window.addEventListener) // older FF
    window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
  window.onwheel = preventDefault; // modern standard
  window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = preventDefault; // older browsers, IE
  window.ontouchmove = preventDefault; // mobile
  document.onkeydown = preventDefaultForScrollKeys;
}

function enableScroll() {
  $(".info > .state").text("Enable");
  if (window.removeEventListener)
    window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
  window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = null;
  window.onwheel = null;
  window.ontouchmove = null;
  document.onkeydown = null;
}
```

```css
html,
body,
.page {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0 15px;
  display: table;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.info {
  background-color: #cdcdcd;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 15px;
  height: 50px;
}

.container {
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  margin: 60px 15px 0 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: auto;
}

.content {
  height: 100000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="info">
      |<label class="position">Initial</label> |
      <label class="state">Enable</label>

      <button class="enable" type="button">Enable</button>
      <button class="disable" type="button">Disable</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

it solution almost work, except cases when user use `scrollbar` or `wheel-click` scrolling. e.g. [not working use case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Wd34.gif) I want scroll will be stopped when achieve limit (in the example `5000px`) and allow scrolling after some event. Is it possible?

**UPDATE**
Actually question is how to stop scrolling during scrolling [**example**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MmNU.gif). Scrolling was disabled when user achieve `5000px`, but `current scrolling process` didn't stopped. And I would like to know is is possible to stop scrolling in progress i.e. in other words how to stop scrolling in the example when position become greater than `5000px` (change color in header to `red`)

Comment: I want to ask why you are doing this. If the issue is that the table is not loaded below that point then presumably there is no more page to scroll to anyway and the scrolling will stop because the bottom of the table is the bottom of the page. If there is more page below that point then why are you stopping people from being able to scroll to it? If you have more page that you dont want people to scroll to then remove it?

Comment: you should check this out [Disable Scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily)

Comment: Table contains next data page. And one of the **strange** use case lazy loading - load pages one by one. And  for that use case I want to be sure that I can't jump over page when user using `scrollbar` or `wheel-click` scrolling. By that reason I need to block scrolling due current page has not loaded yet.

Comment: @imanshu15 actually your response (**Disable Scrolling**) the same as **almost working solution**, and that solution has the same problem, it isn't work with `scrollbar` scrolling. If you call `disableScroll()` scrolling still will be work with scrollbar or whell-click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class

```
.stop-scrolling{
overflow : hidden;
}
```

when you need to stop scroll over page

```
$('html').addClass('stop-scrolling');
```

and when you want to enable it again:

```
$('html').removeClass('stop-scrolling');
```

OR do the same thing like below without adding any class:

```
$('html').css('overflow','hidden');
$('html').css('overflow','auto');
```

Comment: I marked that answer as accepted because if add class and after that remove class that should solve my problem. Current scrolling process stopped and user see no changes at interface (scrollbar doesn't disappear)

Answer (score 0):

Okay i see. Then to disable the scrollbar you should try ,

```
$("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
```

Then to cancel mousewheel scrolling you should try,

```
document.addEventListener("mousewheel", function(evt){

  evt.preventDefault(); 
  return false; 

}, false);
```

Comment: It not completely what I want. Please see update of the question. I tried create more intuitive example. I don't want to hide scrollbar, I want to stop scrolling if it's possible